# Add multiple element using jquery each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, each

I'm new here and I'd like to ask a question about jQuery.
i have some problem with jquery each, and i have code :

```
$("#search-submit").click(function(){
    var item = $("<span>asdf</span>");
    $("body").append(item, item);
}
```

I just can't figure out, why is this simple code don't work. Instead of print "asdf" twice, i just got one "asdf" printed each time i click the button..
this also don't work. this is so silly...

```
$("body").append(item);
$("body").append(item);
```

Thanks a lot... and sorry about my bad english

Denny.

Comment: Append will always append the same item, and will move it if it already exists. Try using item.clone() in your append.

Comment: You haven't closed the click method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append a jQuery object only one time, you can `clone` the object:

```
$("#search-submit").click(function() {
    var item = $("<span>asdf</span>");
    $("body").append(item, item.clone());
})
```

Or append a string:

```
$("#search-submit").click(function() {
    var item = "<span>asdf</span>";
    $("body").append(item, item);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yKyAL/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

```
$("#search-submit").click(function() {
    var item = $("<span>asdf</span>");
    $("#test").append(item.clone(), item.clone());
});​
```

Check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tqN3a/)